# Given $f’(x) = x^2$, derive $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3} + C$ without integration

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Suppose that $f$$:$$\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at every point and that

$$f’(x) = x^2$$

for all $x$. Prove that

$$f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3} + C$$

where $C$ is a constant.

This has to be done without integrating, I have only been taught differential calculus and this question only assumes knowledge of that.

I tried applying mean value theorem and taylor’s approximation but could not come up with the proof. Can someone please provide the solution?

Comment: Can you assume $f$ is a polynomial?

Comment: Why can you not just differentiate $f$?

Comment: I’m not sure, the question is silent on this and I have stated the question verbatim, assuming you can make the assumption how do wee solve it then?

Comment: Do you have the theorem that if $f' = g'$ then $f - g$ is constant?

Comment: An educated guess gives you a candidate $\frac{x^3}{3}$. To show that any such $f$ is of the form $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3} + c$, note first that $g(x) = f(x) - \frac{x^3}{3}$ has zero derivative everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$ and then argue using Mean Value Theorem to show that this implies $g=\text{constant}$.

Comment: @Bungo no do not have this either

Comment: @user601297 I really do not see why you should not simply use the definition of $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and solve it like this. It is a really elemantary calculation and only uses that you already 'know' what the antiderivative is, but as it seems that is given in the task anyways.

Comment: @Cornman you are already taking the value of $f(x)$ as given in the question and then differentiating it to show that $f’(x)$ is as given, the question requires you to go in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be differentiable such that $g'(x) = 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Then the mean value theorem says that for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$ there exists some $\xi$ between them such that $g(x)-g(y) = g'(\xi)(x-y) = 0$. Hence, $g(x)=g(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$ and it follows that $g$ is constant.

Now, consider the function $\phi(x) = \frac 13 x^3$. Its derivative is $\phi'(x) = x^2$. But also your function $f : \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ has that derivative. Consider $g := f-\phi$. We have $g'(x) = f'(x)-\phi'(x) = x^2-x^2 = 0$ for all $x$, so $g$ is a constant, $g(x) = c$, and thus $f(x) = \phi(x) + g(x) = \frac 13x^3 + c$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x) = f(x) - \frac{x^3}{3}$.  What can you say about the derivative of $g(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

Here is to use the Mean-Value-Theorem (MVT) for the derivation. Let $\epsilon$ be small positive variable and observe that,

$$x^2+\frac13\epsilon^2= \frac{6\epsilon x^2+2\epsilon^3}{6\epsilon}
=\frac{(x+\epsilon)^3 - (x-\epsilon)^3}{3(2\epsilon)}
=\frac{g(x+\epsilon)-g(x-\epsilon)}{(x+\epsilon)-(x-\epsilon)}\tag{1}$$

where

$$g(x) = \frac13 x^3$$

According to MVT, the equation (1) can be written as,

$$\frac{g(x+\epsilon)-g(x-\epsilon)}{(x+\epsilon)-(x-\epsilon)}=g'(a)=x^2+\frac13\epsilon^2$$

where $x-\epsilon < a < x+\epsilon$. Now, let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ to obtain,

$$g'(x)=x^2=f'(x)$$

Therefore,

$$f(x) = g(x) +C= \frac13 x^3+C$$